# Определите, попадает ли точка в заданную область

Tags: python, геометрия, координаты

[image: Заданная область]

Я не знаю, какой диапазон включить в код, чтобы он отправлял '+', когда точка находится выше линии x=y, и отправлял '-', когда точка находится ниже линии x=y.

Допустим х=0.1 а у=0.7 при таких значениях код должен отправить ‘+’
А при значениях х=0.5 у=0.1 код должен отправить ‘-‘ тк точка находится вне заданой области, те ниже линии х=у

Я просто не понимаю как разделить на две части правую верхнюю четверть окружности так чтобы при попадании точки в верхнюю часть писался ‘+’, а при попадании в нижнюю часть писался ‘-‘

```
x=float(input(‘Введите координату Х’))
y=float(input(‘Введите координату У’))

if x**2+y**2<=1:
    if x==y 
        print('+')
    elif -1<=x<=0 and 0<=y<=1:
        print('+')
    elif -1<=x<=0 and -1<=y<=0:
        print('+')
    else:
        print('-')
else:
    print('-')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если отдельный вывод для границы не требуется, то так:

```
x*x + y*y <= 1 and (x <= 0 or y >= x)
```

А вот если требуется, то сложнее:

```
if x*x + y*y <= 1 and (x <= 0 or y >= x):
  if x*x + y*y == 1 or x == 0 and y <= 0 or x == y and y >= 0:
    print("На границе")
  else:
    print("Внутри")
else:
  print("Снаружи")
```

Если я правильно представляю возможности питона, то можно записать так:

```
if x*x + y*y <= 1 and (x <= 0 or y >= x):
  if x*x + y*y == 1 or x == 0 >= y and x == y >= 0:
    print("На границе")
  else:
    print("Внутри")
else:
  print("Снаружи")
```

Весь код писал в ответе и не проверял.